# Configuration Settings for PIC18F67K40

Tags: pic

I am using PIC18F67K40 With mikroC. I need Configuration settings for this particular chip

I have referred to the [EVM](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/starter-boards/clicker-2/pic18fk/clicker-2-manual-pic18fk-v201.pdf) of PIC18F67K40 for designing of my custom board.

Edit: I am using external through hole crystal 16MHZ on my custom board.I programmed chip with a small LED blinking program and it is working. I dumped another code but its not working on the chip. Hence i am suspecting the configuration bit settings. 
I have set following on the configuration bit settings:

1. Oscillator selection: HS
2. Low Voltage programming:Enabled
3. MCLR PIN:ENABLED

Do I need to set any other bits?

Comment: You mean like the datasheet of the chip? http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18(L)F67K40%20Data%20Sheet%2040001841D.pdf

Comment: I meant like, Which bits i need to set for my chip to be working?

Comment: The compiler should have the settings in the header file for the chip you are using. If it doesn't, use a compiler which does.

Comment: for MikroC u cant define Configuration settings in source code right ?They need to be set in settings?

Comment: You seem unable to describe what you need in English. Your question should describe what the configurable things in the controller need to do for your custom board. Like how fast the system clocks needs to run. Is an external crystal connected to the controller? There are a lot of features described in the data sheet and only you can know what is required. You have posted a bad question. Edit it soon or a moderator will close it.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Just put the things you mentioned in the question in your configuration bits. Maybe switch off the watchdog. (WDTE = OFF)

Comment: I thinking of installing MPLAB 5.25V with MCC 3.75V and XC8 and verify once

Comment: Verified with MPLAB 5.25V with MCC 3.75V and XC8. Programmed with Small LED blinking program and everything is working fine. Will check other functionalities on the custom board

Comment: You did it, great!!